# Нужен сервис для продажи авиабилетов!

Tags: модульность

Мне нужен на сайт модуль,который бы позволил посетителями искать и бронировать авиабилеты . Если кто-то знает какие-нибудь сайты на эту тематику,то напишите пожалуйста!

Comment: Столкнулась с аналогичной проблемой. Пробовала разные разные сервисы, но ни один из них как хотелось бы не работал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все подобные сервисы платные - халявы здесь нет. Де факто все эти сервисы завязаны на что-то подобное [Amadeus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amadeus_CRS) их в мире считаное количество, но в основном рынок контролируется пресловутым Amadeus+Galileo.

Связывайтесь с ними, заключайте договор и готовьте бабки :)

Comment: не знаю насчет Amadeus, а Galileo/Travelport предоставляет не готовые модули, а свой API для поиска/бронирования билетов. А вот уже их многочисленные клиенты могут предоставить именно готовый модуль